# Posting unicode characters with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, unicode, upload, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to integrate HTML5 drag and drop file upload functionality to my project [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com). The code is written by someone from the [forum](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/kcfinder/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=213). It works fine. The only problem if you are trying to upload files into a directory with name contains special unicode characters (cyrillic etc...).
The directory path, files should be uploaded to, is transferred via $_GET['dir'].
If I use upload button instead of drag'n'drop the upload works and I see

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dir"

files/ÑÐµÑÑ
```

in POST data (using Firebug). The real directory path is `files/тест`.
If I drag and drop files from my computer to the same directory, I got an error

```
String contains an invalid character" code: "5
xhr.sendAsBinary(postbody);
```

The drag and drop works without errors if the directory name I'm trying to upload into, has only non-unicode characters. I tried to encode 'dir' parameter with encodeURIComponent(), but in this case the error is gone, but the responsed PHP gets it encoded ("files/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82")

```
postbody += 'Content-Type: ' + evt.target.thisFileType + '\r\n\r\n' +
    evt.target.result + '\r\n--' + boundary +
    '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dir"\r\n\r\n' +
    encodeURIComponent(evt.target.thisTargetDir) + '\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\n--' +
    boundary + '--\r\n';
```

The project has Git. I cannot post more hyperlinks. You can found it at the SourceForge project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript strings are encoded with UTF-16, as you can see in the URL-encoded string (0xD182 is a UTF-16 code unit, etc.). You should probably encode the string as an explicit UTF-8 string in your AJAX request.

Comment: If you need a Javascript UTF-8 encode routine, you can find one as part of the JS implementation of the MD5 hashing algorithm [over at webtoolkit.info](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html).

Comment: @DaveRandom: Thanks! I had a quick look for how to create UTF8, but I couldn't see a built-in solution. Good stuff.

Comment: "10q"? Never heard that before -- learn a new thing every day, eh? :-)